# Build standalone React component to delivery on CDN using umijs

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, umijs, webpack-chain

After building my React application and MyModule I create an html file for test :

```html
<!-- MAIN.html -->
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="http://localhost/cdn/js/MyModule.js.js"></script>
    <script>
        MyModule.mount()
    </script>
</body>
```

> **Note:** When mounting the component in the admin interface is works fine. But there is No Style loaded in the basic html test.

### Result

[image]

How to load only my **custom css** and a necessary **antd style** without overriding the body css of the `MAIN.html` file ?

> I noticed that `MyModule.js.604c4d96.css` have been generated with hash.

### Expected

I am trying to make React module to delivery as on js file.
In order to achieve this I have create three files `MyComponent.tsx`, `MyComponent.less`, `MyModule.tsx` then add an entry in `config.ts`.

```js
// config.ts
//...
chainWebpack(config) {
  config.entry('MyModule.js').add(path.join(__dirname, '/../src/cdn/js/MyModule.tsx'));
  config.output.filename((chunkData) =>
    chunkData.chunk.name === 'umi' ? '[name].[contenthash:8].js' : 'cdn/js/[name]');
}
//...
```

```js
// MyModule.tsx
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const MyModule = {
  mount(element: string = '#root') {
    const container = window.document.querySelector(element);
    if (!container) {
      throw new Error(`Can't found element ('${element}') in your document`);
    }
    render(<MyComponent />, container);
  },
};

window.MyModule = MyModule;
```

```js
// MyComponent.tsx
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Form, InputNumber, Select } from 'antd';
import styles from './MyComponent.less';

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Form className={styles.MyStyle}>
      <InputNumber />
      <Select />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

```less
/* MyComponent.less */
.MyStyle {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Thank you in advance !